# Problem when creating Dimension in Oracle 10g Express Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dimensions

I have  a problem when I want to create a dimension using Oracle Database 10g Express Edition
and i got the following error message `ORA-00439 materialized view rewrite – feature not enabled`.
I need your help please.

Answer (score 1):

A DIMENSION object is intended to support certain QUERY REWRITE operations in data warehouses.  As the error message suggests, Oracle XE does not support this functionality.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/license.102/b25456/toc.htm#BABJIJCJ).

This is not unreasonable: a datawarehouse which could fit into XE's storage limitations (4GB) would be pretty poor.  So, the question is, why are you trying to build a Data Warehouse in XE?

Answer (score 0):

Join a fact table and a number of dimension tables needs a PL/SQL code.

Thanks.